# Replace function not accepting list as argument - pandas. Getting error TypeError: replace() argument 1 must be str, not list

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

I have searched many past questions but could not find answer to my problem!

I am trying to replace the column names of a data frame by passing two lists. First list (current column names) as to_replace argument and second list as value (new column names). According to the df.replace documentation, one can pass lists:

- list of str, regex, or numeric:

  ```
  - First, if `to_replace` and `value` are both lists, they
    **must** be the same length.
  - Second, if ``regex=True`` then all of the strings in **both**
    lists will be interpreted as regexs otherwise they will match
    directly. This doesn't matter much for `value` since there
    are only a few possible substitution regexes you can use.
  - str, regex and numeric rules apply as above.
  ```

My code is:

```
CurrentColNames=list(df.columns)

NewColNames=['Hello','Hi', ...'Bye'] #Just an example. Lists are of same size and type. 

df.rename(columns={c: c.replace(CurrentColNames,NewColNames) for c in df.columns},inplace=True)
```

I am geeting error:

> TypeError: replace() argument 1 must be str, not list

But documentation said, one can pass lists! Am i missing something? Any help?!

Comment: You're looking for a complicated way to do something simple. Just do: `df.columns = NewColNames`

Comment: @sacul thanks man but i am trying to write a general code becuase often my data file headers have special characters like %, ?, / and so on. Ultimately i am trying to find a way to remove those characters from the header names. I thought it might be a good start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.replace` is used for replacing a DataFrame's *values*, which are distinct from the DataFrame's column names. @sacul is right - the easiest way to do what you want to do, is to simply replace the `.columns` attribute with a new list:

```
df.columns = NewColNames
```

If you have a dictionary mapping current names to new names (let's call it `current_to_new`, you could also use `.rename`:

```
df = df.rename(columns=current_to_new)
```